# committed with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE) at peer1.org1.com:7051

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm just starting out with Hyperledger Fabric (at a really low level):

- I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
- I use: Docker Desktop (Docker compose v2.23.3-desktop.2) , Fabric 2.5.5 and Fabric CA 1.4.

Browsing tutorials online, I built a Fabric network of two organizations, org0 (with 03 orderers) and org1 (with 01 peer) :

- The cryptographic hardware was deployed without a hitch, following the recommendations of : [text](https://medium.com/coinmonks/creating-a-hyperledger-fabric-network-from-scratch-v-1-4-695906dbb7c6)
- the content of my configtx.yaml file is :

```
Organizations:
    - &org0
        Name: org0
# ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: org0
# MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: orderers/org0/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('org0.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('org0.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('org0.admin')"
    - &org1
            # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
            # of the fabric.git development environment
            Name: org1
    # ID to load the MSP definition as
            ID: org1
            MSPDir: peers/org1/msp
            Policies:
                Readers:
                    Type: Signature
                    Rule: "OR('org1.admin', 'org1.peer', 'org1.client')"
                Writers:
                    Type: Signature
                    Rule: "OR('org1.admin', 'org1.client')"
                Admins:
                    Type: Signature
                    Rule: "OR('org1.admin')"
Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true
# Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true
# Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
# Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
# Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer1.org0.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: orderers/org0/orderer1/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
          ServerTLSCert: orderers/org0/orderer1/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
        - Host: orderer2.org0.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: orderers/org0/orderer2/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
          ServerTLSCert: orderers/org0/orderer2/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
        - Host: orderer3.org0.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: orderers/org0/orderer3/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
          ServerTLSCert: orderers/org0/orderer3/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
# Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s
# Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:
# Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10
# Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
# Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
# Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:
# Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
# Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:
    bchannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *org1
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    genesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            Addresses:
                - orderer1.org0.com:7050
                - orderer2.org0.com:7050
                - orderer3.org0.com:7050
            Organizations:
                - *org0
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
            - <<: *org0
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *org1
```

- The content of my docker-compose.yaml file is :

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  orderer1.org0.com:
  orderer2.org0.com:
  orderer3.org0.com:
  peer1.org1.com:
networks:
  fabric:
services:
  orderer1.org0.com:
    hostname: orderer1.org0.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.5.5
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=org0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/keystore/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/cacerts/localhost-8054.pem]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/keystore/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/cacerts/localhost-8054.pem]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./orderers/org0/orderer1/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./orderers/org0/orderer1/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer1.org0.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    networks:
      fabric:
        aliases:
          - orderer1.org0.com
  orderer2.org0.com:
    hostname: orderer2.org0.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.5.5
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=org0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/keystore/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/cacerts/localhost-8054.pem]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/keystore/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/cacerts/localhost-8054.pem]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./orderers/org0/orderer2/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./orderers/org0/orderer2/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer2.org0.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    networks:
      fabric:
        aliases:
          - orderer2.org0.com
  orderer3.org0.com:
    hostname: orderer3.org0.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.5.5
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=org0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/keystore/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/cacerts/localhost-8054.pem]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/keystore/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/cacerts/localhost-8054.pem]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./orderers/org0/orderer3/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./orderers/org0/orderer3/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer3.org0.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    networks:
      fabric:
        aliases:
          - orderer3.org0.com
  peer1.org1.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.com
    hostname: peer1.org1.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.5.5
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=false
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/keystore/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/cacerts/localhost-8054.pem
      # Allow more time for chaincode container to build on install.
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=300s
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org1.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./peers/org1/peer1/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./peers/org1/peer1/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org1.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    networks:
      fabric:
        aliases:
          - peer1.org1.com
  
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:2.5.5
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
#      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
#      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/org1/msp/tlscacerts/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/org1/peer1/msp/user/admin
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./peers/org1/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/org1/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
        - ./chaincode:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode
        - ./orderers/org0/orderer1:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/org0/orderer1
    networks:
      fabric:
```

After my docker container and network had launched without a hitch, I created and joined a channel (ID: bchannel). Using the peer lifecucle chaincode a chaincode was packaged and installed on our counterpart.
but when we tried to approve our chaincode with the command :

```
peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -o orderer1.org0.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/org1/msp/tlscacerts/server.crt --peerAddresses peer1.org1.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/org1/msp/tlscacerts/server.crt --channelID bchannel --name testcc --version 1 --init-required --sequence 1 --waitForEvent --package-id testcc_1:9b8e95e5c62b82ff621ad6cdb6f2f8999e769c6ac97cda78d39a63c5d3d715f0 --signature-policy "AND('org1.peer')"
```

we get the following error:

```
**2024-02-08 11:23:20.929 UTC 0001 INFO [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> txid [8e551a7f10fdcc0146982a19d0a7ce503f8508a0f0aadd47d4a71dfe11b1f6b6] committed with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE) at peer1.org1.com:7051
Error: transaction invalidated with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE)**
```

We tried to look for solutions online, but either we didn't understand them well (given our level), or they simply didn't work in our case.

We really need help to correct this error - we've been at it for** 02 weeks **now.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Looks your configtx.yaml  is old or not have the endorsement stanza under org1. Use the latest configtx.yaml from fabric samples. its suppose to have below.

```
  Endorsement:
    Type: Signature
    Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"
```

Comment: Okay @ravinayag, thanks for the feedback.
I'll edit my configtx.yaml file and get back to you.

Comment: My dear @ravinayag , I'm back, I adjusted my configtx.yaml file , I generated new channel artifacts, I created a new one which was joined by my peer.
I typed the following command : `peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -o orderer1.org0.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/org1/msp/tlscacerts/server.crt --channelID testxchannel --name testcc --version 1 --init-required --sequence 1 --waitForEvent --package-id testcc_1:9b8e95e5c62b82ff621ad6cdb6f2f8999e769c6ac97cda78d39a63c5d3d715f0`.     `Error: timed out waiting for txid on all peers`

Comment: This time I get the following error:  `Error: timed out waiting for txid on all peers`

Comment: According to error, it's not able to communicate with peers, 
Are you using the `cli` container to execute the `peer lifecycle chaincode` commands?

Comment: Yes I use the Cli container to execute the peer lifecycle chaincode.